# WPF AutoCompleteBox Using Database

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

We are implementing a desktop application that requires dynamic auto-complete box that should both the name and image. I thought using WPF Toolkit AutoCompleteBox looked like a good fit but I'm having trouble getting everything wired up with MVVM and connecting to the database.

My problem at the moment is related to not being able to propagate the Populating event to the ViewModel. It wants to create a method in the code behind, and I need it in my view model. It seems AutoCompleteBox doesn't have a Command available.

Here is my XAML

```
<controls1:AutoCompleteBox Name="PatientSearchBox"
                                               ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}"
                                               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatient, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PatientAutoCompleteTemplate}"
                                               ItemFilter="{Binding PersonFilter}"
                                               ValueMemberPath="DisplayName"
                                               Command="{Binding PopulatingCommand}">
                    </controls1:AutoCompleteBox>
```

And the ViewModel

```
public class PatientSearchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private IPatientService _patientService;

        private IEnumerable<PatientSearch> _patients;
        private PatientSearch _selectedPatient;

        public RelayCommand<PopulatingEventArgs> PopulatingCommand { get; set; }

        public PatientSearchViewModel()
        {
            PopulatingCommand = new RelayCommand<PopulatingEventArgs>(OnPopulatingCommand);
            _patientService = new PatientService();
        }

        public IEnumerable<PatientSearch> Patients
        {
            get { return _patients; }
            set
            {
                _patients = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public PatientSearch SelectedPatient
        {
            get { return _selectedPatient; }
            set
            {
                _selectedPatient = value;
            }
        }

        public AutoCompleteFilterPredicate<object> PersonFilter
        {
            get
            {
                return (searchText, obj) =>
                (obj as PatientSearch).FirstName.Contains(searchText)
                || (obj as PatientSearch).LastName.Contains(searchText);
            }
        } 

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void OnPopulatingCommand(PopulatingEventArgs e)
        {
            Patients = _patientService.SearchPatients(e.Parameter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know that control, but it looks like it has a Populating event? Easiest thing would be type `Populating="` as an attribute on the control tag and let intellisense create the event handler in the view. In the handler cast the view's DataContext to your viewmodel type, and call the vm's handler. If Command IS how it populates, vm needs a PopulateCommand property that returns a command -- an object implementing `ICommand`.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but even if you get this working that is a lot of round trips to the database.  I download the values to a SortedList when the app starts and add any value the user added to the SortedList.  Yes they miss values added by other during the session much better performance and take a load off the database server.